# Symfony2, refactorisation, one or many flush()?

Tags: php, symfony, refactoring

I'm trying to refactor my code in my controller.

For now, i have all treatments in this controller and i finish with a `flush()` in an action.

So, in an action, i can have many `persist()` and just one `flush()` at the end.

I'm working now to clean my controller, and create functions in all my repository to reduce the code.

But now i have a problem, if, before, for an action i was 10 `persist()` and 1 `flush()`, now i have `10 flush()` (one for each repository-function).

I think it is not a good solution to increase the number of `flush()` like that, right ?

I have find something and i want to now, if with this code, there is always 10 `flush()` each time ? Or just one when `commit()` ?

```
$em->getConnection()->beginTransaction(); // suspend auto-commit
try {
    //... do some work
    $user = new User;
    $user->setName('George');
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
    $em->getConnection()->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $em->getConnection()->rollback();
    $em->close();
    throw $e;
}
```

Comment: I would postpone any `flush` as much as possible even if manual transaction management is used :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example it's a transaction, which is good if you want to recover your flushed changes if an Exception occurs. In transactions the `commit()` will actually save your work, and the `rollback()` will revert the changes.

In general situation you should avoid too much `flush()` as wll, because it's consume your resources, and there will be a lot unnecessary database action. I think the repository is mainly for finding querys and not for "flushing" querys. If you want to do every "flush query" in repository, you may want to persist the classes in your repostory and at the end of your controller you can flush the `EntityManager`.

Comment: Yes, for now, i persist in repository, and flush a the end of my controller. But like that, i can't use a repository-function alone. I always need to flush after in my controller.

Comment: And if i have 40 flush in my transaction (in the try), they are executed when commit() ? Or they are executed 40 times.. ?

Comment: I think they will be executed, so you should avoid repetitive flush() in transactions as well. The transactions are in the DBMS layer, so the MySQL/PostgreSQL/... will handle the transaction, but the flush() is handled by Doctrine.